# How to submit additional variables alongside form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form that works properly and stores all variables ('firstname', 'lastname', etc.) in the `GET` array.

At the time of form submission, I need to pass an additional variable in the `GET` array to let the PHP controller know to display the next set of prompts. Something simple like `step=2`.

What I tried doing was setting the form action to `?step=2` as well as `?step=2&`. But, no matter what I try, the form's variables are all that show up in the URL.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a hidden form field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['step'] = 2;
```

PS: Or a session var XD

Saludos.